# Page jump without name or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to jump to a spot in someone else's page. I know I can do this by appending to the url a '#' with the name attribute of the element I want to jump to, e.g.

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/#footer-container">Click!</a>
```

But what if I want to jump to a spot on their page that doesn't have an id or a name? Can I do a page jump by first instance of an element name or class? Can I scroll down the page a certain amount of pixels? Is there another way to page jump to a spot on someone else's page without ids or names?

I don't mind using javascript/jquery.

**UPDATE**
In many browsers, like Chrome for example, there is a console to edit a page's scripts, such as its HTML, CSS, and JS. On the page I am currently on, I can open the js console, grab the element 'body' and change it's CSS to 'position: absolute; top: -1000px', which would essentially 'scroll down' the way that I need it to.
Can I do this to a page in an iframe in any way shape or form, without the cross-origin error stuff?

Comment: Nope, don't think u can do that.

Comment: I sometimes wish that were possible too.

Comment: theoretically it can be done - using iframes with our javascript as one option (not neccesarily working for all target sites) or using some backend as a proxy and inserting our javascript - also keen to  failure if target sites employ some protection... but if you can think of other way around - parse target site DOM with your backend and show it on your site - that would work, if it's a concept you can apply to your general intention...

Comment: @nettutvikler I tried iframes, but I get those cross-origin policy errors. Those other ideas are interesting though. How would I go about that method of parsing the target site?

Comment: Yes, many pages protect itself and don't allow it... Parsing is tricky too, but just getting HTML should be no problem. What backend possibilities have you (PHP/Java/node/...)? PHP have some built-in functions and there are plenty of open source classes that do the job pretty well. Java have many advanced things too (proxy-like etc), so it really depends on backend of your choice and content you want to parse. But - as a rule - if you target some div's on target page (with id or class) and if owner change anything - you have a problem...

Comment: @nettutvikler PHP is my backend of choice, and I just learned today of the possibility of using the file_get_contents() function to grab the html of the site into my page. It's really just to make a site for my personal convenience, nothing large scale. If I borrowed the site's stylesheet and linked it in my file, I think I'd be set. Any other PHP tricks I could use?

Comment: Great, yes, I would try with that first and if it would not be "enough" you can look into fopen() with stream context or cURL with setopt that are way more "powerfull" (cookies, auth, etc).